# Why do I get two copies of my printer?

Tags: 22.04, printing

My printer is attached via ethernet to my LAN.  When I install it I get two copies shown. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: [this post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2493027) may provide the clue. The second printer, driverless was installed in 22.04 automatically and you installed a specific driver for the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[this Q&A](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2493027) from Ubuntu Forums holds the clue.

The second (driverless) printer was installed automatically by the system and you also installed a specific driver for the first, effectively the same printer.

You can use either for printing. Just select which you want to be the default.

Comment: I didn't actually install a driver. I just clicked  "add printer".

Comment: same issue - you added a printer to one already installed automatically by the system. I have the same on my instance of 22.04 however, on my 23.10 instance (upgraded from a vanilla install of 23.04) I did not use `add printer` and only the driverless one is present. It's really nothing to be unduly concerned about. I use one for single sided printing and the other for duplex printing, for example. Both work perfectly well.